# Decimals in R from Excel

Tags: r, excel, decimal

I am trying to upload an excel file into R. My excel data has decimals, however, R is either truncating or adding decimals. How could R show the exact decimals as in the excel file?

I am attaching a picture showing View(inventory) in R and the excel file. The problem is in the "material" column (R is truncating some decimals). The code I used to load the data is the following:

```
library(readxl)
inventory <- read_excel("inventory.xlsx", sheet=1)
```

I wanted to share the excel file to make it completely reproducible, but I was not able to do it. As I know I am not providing a reproducible content, I just wanted to know if someone has any idea about this issue. Maybe you have already faced a similar situation.

[image: R vs Excel decimals]

Comment: What is stored in memory and what is printed to the screen can differ due to rounding or truncation during the display process.  To get a quick view of the value stored in memory, try `print(inventory, digits=20)`.

Comment: Thank you DanY for your insight! I tried and it worked perfectly well.